# Integrate Angular 11 to existing .Net Core 3.1 MVC application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an existing .NET Core 3.1 MVC application running on Azure Web Apps and I like to integrate it with Angular 11.

I tried to google and found some articles around it but don't know if they are the best approach to move forward.

https://www.dotnetfocus.com/add-multiple-angular-7-apps-to-existing-dot-net-core-project/

https://mithunvp.com/angular-asp-net-mvc-5-angular-cli-visual-studio-2017/

I'm not sure how the application routing will work and does integration has to go through integrating the angular tags into .cshtml file so that the user can access the other module by redirecting from on view of .cshtml to other like usual Core MVC application works?

Comment: Both the MVC and Angular has their own routing configure to implement navigation. From your description, it seems that you want to render the angular component on the MVC view page, right? I'm not sure why you want to do that, why not directly using the angular to render the page source and use the MVC application as the API (get data from the controller action method). Besides, according the links, you could create an angular application in the ClientApp folder, but you have to start its own instance of the Angular CLI server in the background.

Comment: If you want to create an SPA application, I suggest you could refer to this tutorial: [Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: I would love to use angular to render the page but how the application will know where to find the angular page route?

Comment: Or angular page routing will be handled by angular cli and "ng serve" command will take care of the routing for me ?

Comment: Yes, the angular page routing will be handled by angular. You could find them in your angular application. By using the `npm start` or `ng serve`, you will start its own instance of the Angular CLI server in the background, then you could access the angular page via the angular page routing.